# Filling a DataGridView by Month and Year using Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

I need help with something.

I have a `DataGridView (dgv)` that I am filling it with data from a txt file.

The dgv is:

```
J | F | M | A | M | J | J | A | S | O | N | D
  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

In that txt file I have thousands of records in the following way:

`id1_id2_date1_date2_data1_data2_data3_..._num1_num2_bool1_bool2_bool3`

I'm reading line by line using a StreamReader. Each line into an object `Record b`. Then I'm getting `b.date.Month` into a `switch` to split the records by month. The info I need from the records is `num1`. I used a `Dictionary<int, int>` to do it. So:

```
<1,x>
<2,x>
...
<12,x>
```

Each dictionary has all the records belonging to that month regardless of the year. Here using X for those records.

```
J | F | M | A | M | J | J | A | S | O | N | D
x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
```

But NOW I need to do this:

```
  Y   | J | F | M | A | M | J | J | A | S | O | N | D
2015  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
2016  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
2017  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
2018  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
2019  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
...
```

**But I'm stuck. I can't figure it out.** I thought about something like `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>` but that won't work because the year is dynamic information.

The code:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FileStream fs;
  Dictionary<int, int> dataByMonth = new Dictionary<int, int>();
  Record b;

  try
  {
    if (File.Exists("data.txt"))
    {
      fs = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
      {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
          b = new Record(sr.ReadLine());

          // Get the month
          int month = b.date1.Month;
          
          // Thx to Steve for pointing out the unnecessary switch
          if (!dataByMonth.ContainsKey(month))
            dataByMonth.Add(m, b.num1);
          else
            dataByMonth[month] += b.num1;
        }
      }

      string str = string.Empty;
      foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> x in dataByMonth)
      {
        str += x.Value.ToString() + "_";
      }

      string[] str1 = str.Split('_');
      dgv.Rows.Add(str1);
    }
  }
}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Help?

Comment: The switch seems to be totally unecessary.

Comment: The use of dictionary also seems unnecessary. Why not just use an array of `int`s for each year and hold this in a dictionary?

Comment: @Steve thx for that. I don't know how I did that. I'm gonna edit my main post.

Comment: @greenjaed I think I see your point. I'm gonna see if I can work it out. Thx!

Comment: `var records = File.ReadLines("data.txt").Select(line => new Record(line)).ToList();` Then you can `GroupBy` the year, and within those you can `GroupBy` months.

Comment: @RufusL you nailed it. Took me a few hours to get it right because I don't find LINQ an easy tool to work with. Edit: Can you make your comment a post so I can mark it as an answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the main post's comment section, as the author didn't make it as an answer.
Here: [Filling a DataGridView by Month and Year using Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911948/filling-a-datagridview-by-month-and-year-using-dictionary/66912759?noredirect=1#comment118279341_66911948)

Answer (score 0):

What does your `Record` class look like?

I think it would be simplest to modify the constructor of your `Record` class to translate and store the values that you want from each line, in a `List<Record>` or something like that. Then you can use LINQ to query against your list and `groupby` month, do an aggregate on the num, etc.

Something like:

```
public class Record
{
    public DateTime RecordDate {get;set;}
    public int RecordMonth {get;set;}
    public int RecordYear {get;set;}
    public int TheCount {get;set;}

  public Record(string lineIn)
  {
      var splitValues = lineIn.Split('_');
      int outNum;
      TheCount = int.TryParse(splitValues[7], out outNum)?outNum:0;
      var inDateString = splitValues[2];
      DateTime outDate;
      RecordDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(inDateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outDate)? outDate : DateTime.MinValue;
      RecordMonth = RecordDate.Month;
      RecordYear = RecordDate.Year;
  }
}
```

And then in your streamreader, something more like:

```
var theData = new List<Record>();
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
  theData.Add(new Record(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

And now you can work with your data via LINQ. Using groupby, etc.

Here is a full sample (and link to dot net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AmuMiq)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var records = new List<Record>();
        
        //pattern = id1_id2_date1_date2_data1_data2_data3_..._num1_num2_bool1_bool2
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-03-01_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_51_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-03-02_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_62_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-03-03_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_73_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-03-04_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_34_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-03-05_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_25_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-04-01_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_56_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-04-02_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_67_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-04-03_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_78_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-04-04_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_39_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-04-05_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_20_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-05-01_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_59_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-05-02_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_68_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-05-03_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_77_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-05-04_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_36_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2020-05-05_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_25_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-03-01_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_54_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-03-02_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_63_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-03-03_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_72_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-03-04_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_31_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-03-05_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_20_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-04-01_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_51_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-04-02_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_62_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-04-03_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_73_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-04-04_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_34_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-04-05_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_25_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-05-01_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_56_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-05-02_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_67_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-05-03_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_78_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-05-04_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_39_100_true_false"));
        records.Add(new Record("abc_def_2021-05-05_2019-01-01_hello_hello_hello_20_100_true_false"));
        
        // this will create a list of anonymous type. If it makes more sense, you could create a class to model
        // the tabular data as well
        var shapedData = records.GroupBy(x => new {x.RecordYear, x.RecordMonth})
            .Select(x => new {
                Year = x.Key.RecordYear,
                Month = x.Key.RecordMonth,
                Total = x.Sum(i=>i.TheCount)
            })
            .ToList();
        
        foreach(var item in shapedData){
            Console.WriteLine($"Year: {item.Year} Month: {item.Month} Total: {item.Total}");
        }
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public DateTime RecordDate {get;set;}
    public int RecordMonth {get;set;}
    public int RecordYear {get;set;}
    public int TheCount {get;set;}

  public Record(string lineIn)
  {
      var splitValues = lineIn.Split('_');
      int outNum;
      TheCount = int.TryParse(splitValues[7], out outNum)?outNum:0;
      var inDateString = splitValues[2];
      DateTime outDate;
      RecordDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(inDateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outDate)? outDate : DateTime.MinValue;
      RecordMonth = RecordDate.Month;
      RecordYear = RecordDate.Year;
  }
}
```

Provides the following output:

```
Year: 2020 Month: 3 Total: 245
Year: 2020 Month: 4 Total: 260
Year: 2020 Month: 5 Total: 265
Year: 2021 Month: 3 Total: 240
Year: 2021 Month: 4 Total: 245
Year: 2021 Month: 5 Total: 260
```

Comment: My Record class does that for each value that composes the record. The problem is I do not understand LINQ. I tried once I found it quite hard and confusing.

Comment: I think LINQ is going to make this a lot more straightforward... I will edit my response with some updated code showing `GroupBy`

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem already. Here: https://imgur.com/a/yea6woP
I was so focused that this has to be solved with Dictionary that I couldn't let go to think of other solutions. Though, still need to properly understand LINQ.
The result I was looking for: https://imgur.com/a/i9YTY55